# Is there an API to get feeds from My Yahoo's page?

Tags: android, api, rss, yahoo

I want to write an RSS agregator for Android, so I want to get feeds from user's My Yahoo page. Is there an API to do so?
I spend a whole day to find it but there is no success.
Perhaps somebody know how to do that. Thanks

Comment: The My Yahoo page is essentially an aggregator to begin with. While I don't know of any method to retrieve a list of feeds a user is subscribed to, if it exists it's probably going to be on the Yahoo API site. http://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html Have a look at Pipes.

Comment: I found only [this](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/005384.html), but it is deprecated and does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after few days I found solution.

- First step is to parse hidden values from Yahoo login page.
- Second step is to make POST request with this values
- And finally parse from MyYahoo user's page feeds url